# fancybox causes deprecated font warning in minted/pygments

Tags: warnings, minted, fancybox

I use minted package for syntax highlighting. It generates code [like this](http://pastebin.com/GH6uJkvG).

I recently added the fancybox package and immediately all my minted statements yield this warning in abundance:

```
Class scrbook Warning: Usage of deprecated font command `\tt'!
(scrbook)              You should note, that in 1994 font command `\tt' has
(scrbook)              been defined for compatiblitiy to Script 2.0 only.
(scrbook)              Now, after two decades of LaTeX2e and NFSS2, you
(scrbook)              shouldn't use such commands any longer and within
(scrbook)              KOMA-Script usage of `\tt' is definitely deprecated.
(scrbook)              See `fntguide.pdf' for more information about
(scrbook)              recommended font commands.
(scrbook)              Note also, that KOMA-Script will remove the definition
(scrbook)              of `\tt' anytime until release of about version 3.20.
(scrbook)              But for now, KOMA-Script will replace deprecated `\tt'
(scrbook)              by `\normalfont \ttfamily ' on input line 54.
```

I have *hundreds* of these. Why is fancybox interfering with minted, and how can I make them play nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fancybox` package uses three times `\tt` which has been a deprecated command for more than 20 years. `:-(`

You can fix it by redefining the `fancybox` to correctly call `\normalfont\ttfamily`:

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
% fix the bad commands in fancybox.sty
{\catcode`\ =12\gdef\ttspace{{\normalfont\ttfamily }}}
\def\VerbatimFont{\normalfont\ttfamily}
\def\VerbFont{\normalfont\ttfamily}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, although I've since noticed that fancybox *completely breaks* minted rendering. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[enabledeprecatedfontcommands,...]{scrbook}
```

or write to the package author(s) that they should use `\ttfamily` instead of `\tt`.